# Pointer Swapping Rules

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I have a few questions regarding the rules of using pointers and arrays, as I am little confused about the rules regarding passing arrays around.

```
void f1(int* x, int* y) {
  int * ptr = x;
  x = y;
  y = ptr;
}

void f2(int* x, int* y) {
  int val = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = val;
}
void f3(int* x, int* y) {
  int val = *x;
  x = y;
  y = &val;
}
```

So let's say I have two arrays, `a[3] = {0,2,4}` and `b[3] = {1,3,5}`.

If I run the lines `f1(arr_a, arr_b);` & `printf("%d\n", *arr_a);` it will print out 0. I am assuming this is because since you are only passing a pointer of the array to the function, it is only a copy of the array, so nothing is actually modified. Would this assumption be correct?

Now, if I run `f2(arr_a + 1, arr_b + 1)` and `printf("%d\n", *(arr_a + 1));`, it would result in a value of 3, and this is because since I am not using a pointer this time, I am directly using an integer (val), which is being set equal to the value of the array at an index of 1, and swapping those values. I am assuming because this manually changes the address, unlike the first function, which uses a pointer, which is a copy of the array?

And finally, for the third one, if I run `f3(arr_a + 1, arr_b + 1)` and `printf("%d\n", *(arr_a + 1));` the value should be 2 for x and 3 for y, since x is not swapped with y because the * operator is not used (so addresses are not swapped), and y is being set to the address of val, which is some random address, which also regardless does not get swapped?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First, when passing an array type as a function argument, the array isn't actually passed, but instead the address of the first element is passed.  So for an array `a`, the following two calls are equivalent:

```
f(a);
f(&a[0]);
```

Regarding your specific examples:

1. The call `f1(arr_a, arr_b);` passes the address of the first element of `arr_a` and the address of the first element of `arr_b`.  It's equivalent to `f1(&arr_a[0], &arr_b[0]);`.
   Nothing is copied, other than the addresses that are passed to the function.  The function itself is given its own local copies of the two address.  Even though it modifies them, those changes are confined to the function, and have no effect on the caller.  All it's doing is making some local variable assignments.  In fact, a good optimizer would completely eliminate the function body, since it doesn't do anything.
2. The call `f2(arr_a + 1, arr_b + 1);` passes the addresses of the second elements of `arr_a` and `arr_b`.  It is equivalent to `f2(&arr_a[1], &arr_b[1]);`  Again, nothing is copied.  However, function `f2` dereferences those pointers, swapping their targets.  So the values at index `1` in `arr_a` and `arr_b` are swapped.
3. The call `f3(arr_a + 1, arr_b + 1);` passes the addresses of the second elements of `arr_a` and `arr_b`.  It is equivalent to `f3(&arr_a[1], &arr_b[1]);`  Again, nothing is copied.  The function `f3` loads the value of `arr_a[1]`, then does a few local assignments.  Like `f1`, this function has no effect, and a good optimizer would completely eliminate the function body.

To summarize, functions `f1` and `f3` do nothing and their bodies will likely be optimized away.  Function `f2` is the only one that does something useful, which is to swap the targets of its two pointer arguments.

Answer (score 0):

> it is only a copy of the array, so nothing is actually modified. Would this assumption be correct?

There is no copy of array is created. When you access an array, it is converted to a pointer to first element (there are few *exceptions* to this rule). So, it is just the pointer to first element of array `arr_a` and array `arr_b` assigned to function `f1()` parameters (integer pointers) `x` and `y` respectively. In `f1()` function, the pointers `x` and `y` get swapped i.e. `y` will point to first element of array `arr_a` and `x` will point to first element of array `arr_b`. Function `f1()` result in no change in any element of array `arr_a` and `arr_b`. After calling this function, the print statement

```
printf("%d\n", *arr_a);
```

is printing `0` because `*arr_a` is equivalent to `arr_a[0]`<sup>1)</sup> which is nothing but first element of array `arr_a` whose value is `0`.

```
*arr_a -> *(arr_a + 0) -> *((arr_a) + (0)) -> arr_a[0]
```

> I am assuming because this manually changes the address, unlike the first function, which uses a pointer, which is a copy of the array?

No, it does not change the address, it changes **value** at the address, pointed by pointer `x` and `y`, which you have passed to function `f2()` as arguments. Pointer `x` is holding the address of second element of array `arr_a` and at that address, an integer value exist. When you dereference `x` (i.e. `*x`), that means, you are accessing value at that address. When you assign any value to `*x`, that means, you are modifying the value at that address. Same is with pointer `y`. When the function `f2()` returns the change persist because you have modified the value at the address passed to this function (using the pointer `x` and `y`).

Now the `arr_a` elements are `{0, 3, 4}` and `arr_b` elements are `{1, 2, 5}`.

The print statement

```
printf("%d\n", *(arr_a + 1));
```

will result in printing the second element of array `arr_a` whose value is `3`.

> the value should be 2 for x and 3 for y, since x is not swapped with y because the * operator is not used (so addresses are not swapped), and y is being set to the address of val, which is some random address, which also regardless does not get swapped?

In function `f3()`, you are passing the address of second element of array `arr_a` and `arr_b`. They get assigned to parameter `x` and `y` respectively. Lets look, what is happening after execution of each statement of function `f3()` body:

Statement I of `f3()`

```
int val = *x;
```

Pointer `x` is pointing to second element of array `arr_a`. Dereferencing `x` (i.e. `*x`) will give the value at that address which is `3` and this value assigned to a local variable `val` of function `f3()`.

Statement II of `f3()`

```
x = y;
```

Pointer `y` is pointing to second element of array `arr_b`. After this statement, both `x` and `y` will point to second element of array `arr_b`.

Statement III of `f3()`

```
y = &val;
```

Pointer `y` is assigned the address of local variable `val` which hold the copy of value of second element of array `arr_a`.

So, before exiting the function `f3()`, `x` is pointing to second element of `arr_b` and `y` is pointing to a local variable `val`.

No changes made to any value at address passed to `f3()`, hence the array `arr_a` and `arr_b` state will be same after returning from function `f3()`.

The `arr_a` elements are `{0, 3, 4}` and `arr_b` elements are `{1, 2, 5}` and printing the second element of `arr_a` will result in output `3`.

---

1. From C Standards#6.5.2.1

> The definition of the subscript operator [] is that E1[E2] is identical to (*((E1)+(E2)))..

Comment: To complete the confusion, because of the cited statement of 6.5.2.1 the expression `0[arr_a]` is equivalent to `arr_a[0]`, and it is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 0):

> it is only a copy of the array, so nothing is actually modified. Would
> this assumption be correct?

In this call:

```
f1(arr_a, arr_b);
```

that would be more correctly to write like:

```
f1(a, b);
```

because you declared arrays a and b there is nothing copied. The array designators a and b are implicitly converted to pointers to their first elements. The call above is equivalent to:

```
f1( &a[0], &b[0]);
```

These pointers are passed to the function `f1` by value. That is the function deals with copies of the values of the pointers.

Within the function:

```
void f1(int* x, int* y) {
  int * ptr = x;
  x = y;
  y = ptr;
}
```

these copies are swapped. Changing the copies does not influence on the original arrays used as arguments. After exiting the function the local variables x and y will not be alive.

To make it clear consider the following code snippet. Let's assume that there are two variables a and b of the type int:

```
int a = 0;
int b = 1;
```

and then there is the following code:

```
int x = a;
int y = b;

int tmp = x;
x = y;
y = tmp;
```

As you can see it is copies of the values of the variables a and b assigned to the variables `x` and `y` were swapped. The variables `a` and `b` stay unchanged.

> Now, if I run f2(arr_a + 1, arr_b + 1) and printf("%d\n", *(arr_a +
> 1));, it would result in a value of 3, and this is because since I am
> not using a pointer this time, I am directly using an integer (val),
> which is being set equal to the value of the array at an index of 1,
> and swapping those values. I am assuming because this manually changes
> the address, unlike the first function, which uses a pointer, which is
> a copy of the array?

In this call:

```
f2(a + 1, b + 1);
```

you are again using pointers but now they are pointers to second elements of the arrays. Within the function `f2`:

```
void f2(int* x, int* y) {
  int val = *x;
  *x = *y;
  *y = val;
}
```

there are swapped the second elements of the arrays pointed to by the pointers. That is for example dereferencing the pointer `x` like:

```
*x = *y;
```

you get a direct access to the object pointed to by the pointer `x` and can change the object.

The third function f3:

```
void f3(int* x, int* y) {
  int val = *x;
  x = y;
  y = &val;
}
```

just does not make a sense. It swaps nothing. In the first declaration of the function the local variable `val` gets the value of the object pointed to by the pointer `x`:

```
  int val = *x;
```

Then the local variable `x` gets the value of another local variable `y`:

```
  x = y;
```

And at last the local variable `y` gets the address of the local variable `val`:

```
  y = &val;
```

After exiting the function all its local variables val, x, and y will not be alive. Neither object in the arrays a and b passed to the function through pointers were not changed.